Loop stops executing without error & how to store loop result after each iteration?
While trying to build insurance model for my R course, I found that Rstudio stops executing the code, not giving any error.
For example, I have section where I assign variables:
payout_reserve <- probab/12*T*N*F
Result = W-payout_reserve
a <- (N*probab)/12 
St <- payout_reserve - ( a * F )

This is executed when this is not included in the loop (run selected lines), but this is not executed when this is included in the loop (see code marked bold below):
K<-200 #monthly payment
F<-40000 #potential payout
T<-2 # no of months
probab<-0.03 # 3% probability of payout

#1st period
t<-1

#W=money inflow

**for (t in 1:T) {
    W <-K*N*T } 
#A
#simulation function:
simulation<-function(N, K, F, T,probab) {
 
  for (t in 1:T) {
payout_reserve <- probab/12*T*N*F
#difference between inflow and outflow
Result = W-payout_reserve
#B. number of payouts
a <- (N*probab)/12 
#C. insurance payout
St <- payout_reserve - ( a * F )**


  
#D. liquidity check
n <- sample(0:100, 1) #random number – new customers (0-100)
o <- sample(0:90, 1) #random number – resigning customers (0-100)




if(St>=0){
  print("sufficient liquidity")
  N=N+n-o-a
  } else if (St<0) {
  print ("no liquidity")
    stop("stop")
    }

#E. t=t+1
inc <- function(t) {eval.parent(substitute(t <- t + 1))}
inc(t)

#F. if  ≤ , go to point 2, otherwise exit
while (t <= T) {
  if(t == T){
    break
  }
next 
}
}
}

simulation(N=10000, K=200, F=30000, T=2,probab=0.03) 

Can you please advise what is going on? Why loop does not execute all code?
Also, can you please advise how to store iteration result in a list?
I wanted to have a list of St values  after each iteration...

there are some issues

Inside the simulation() function, the variable W is used but not
defined in the loop. It's defined in a separate loop outside the
function (W <- KNT), which won't apply inside the function due to
scoping.

The while (t <= T) loop can lead to an infinite loop because t isn't
updated inside the loop correctly. You should increment t directly
within the for loop instead of using a while loop.

The next statement is misplaced inside the while loop, which might
prevent the loop from running as expected.

To store the iteration results, you need to initialize a list (or
another data structure) outside the loop and append St values to it
during each iteration and then output it using return

The stop() function halts the entire execution when liquidity is
insufficient. If this is intentional, it’s fine, but it terminates
the whole simulation immediately.


Here is the corrected code:
# Simulation function
simulation <- function(N, K, F, T, probab) {
  
  # Initialize variables
  t <- 1 # Start period
  W <- K * N * T # Initial money inflow
  St_values <- list() # List to store St values for each iteration
  
  for (t in 1:T) {
    # A. Payout reserve
    payout_reserve <- probab / 12 * T * N * F
    
    # B. Difference between inflow and outflow
    Result <- W - payout_reserve
    
    # C. Number of payouts
    a <- (N * probab) / 12
    
    # D. Insurance payout
    St <- payout_reserve - (a * F)
    
    # Store `St` in the list
    St_values[[t]] <- St
    
    # E. Liquidity check
    n <- sample(0:100, 1) # Random new customers
    o <- sample(0:90, 1)  # Random resigning customers
    
    if (St >= 0) {
      print("sufficient liquidity")
      N <- N + n - o - a
    } else {
      print("no liquidity")
      stop("Simulation stopped due to insufficient liquidity.")
    }
    
    # F. Increment time (handled by the for loop)
  }
  
  # Return the list of St values
  return(St_values)
}

# Run the simulation
result <- simulation(N = 10000, K = 200, F = 30000, T = 2, probab = 0.03)


St_df <- data.frame(period = 1:length(result), St = unlist(result))
print(St_df)


Thank you very much for help G-Man! It is exactly what I was looking for. Now I will know how to properly run loops in the future....

Glad to hear that :)
